# Can $S_4$ be generated by $(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I am having troubles answering it. It sometimes confuses me. I could really use some help.

Comment: Which generating sets do you know?

Comment: I am a bit weak in this... 
We never really focused on generating sets.

Comment: So you have not seen any? In that case there is not much else to do but show that any permutation can be written as a product of the given ones.

Comment: More generally, $\left(1,2\right), \left(1,3\right), ..., \left(1,n\right)$ generate $S_n$ for every $n$. To prove this, try writing the adjacent transpositions $\left(i,i+1\right)$ as compositions of these ones.

Answer (score 2):

For example, do you know that in general $\;S_n=\langle\;(1\;2)\;,\;\;(1\;2\;\ldots n)\;\rangle\;$ ? If so, observe that

$$(1 4)(13)(12)=(1234)$$

and thus...

Comment: Yes, but that's using a harder result to prove an easier one!

Comment: @DerekHolt In general I must say that I agree with that, though in many sites it is stated, with or without proof, that those two are a "minimal generators set" and etc., so I thought the OP could have read that at least. A more basic approach could perhaps be to show those three transpositions generate *all* the transpositions in $\;S_4\;$ . Perhaps I'll add an edit on that later. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach/answer is to check that with those three transpositions one can make the rest of them in $S_{4}. After that check that with all the transpositions you can make all the permutations.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Say you have three persons $A$, $B$ and $C$. Initially they are seated on seats $1$, $2$ and $3$. Now, say you want to have persons $B$ and $C$ exchange seats, that is, $B$ should get to seat $3$ and $C$ to seat $2$. However, the only moves allowed is to have the persons on seats $1$ and $2$ exchange seats, or the persons on seats $1$ and $3$ exchange seats. How to switch $B$ and $C$ by performing several of the allowed moves?

In general, you can permute them in any way, with seat $1$ as "processing center".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know that $S_4$ is generated by all transpositions like $(ij)$ (here $i,j \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $i<j$), it is sufficient to show that $(ij)$ can be represented as a product of $(12),(13),(14)$. Then consider the following equality:
$$
  (ij)=(1j)\cdot(1i)\cdot(1j).
$$

**Update:** Any permutation can be presented as a product of independent cycles. And any cycle can be presented as a product of transpositions $(ij)$. For example, 
$$
  (a_1 a_2 \ldots a_k) = (a_1 a_2)(a_1 a_3) \ldots (a_1 a_k).
$$